# How to use user ID(not cookie) to personalize content

Tags: 2013-sp1, profiling, personalization

I'm trying to personalize content by using "Profiling and personalization".
By default, Tridion seems to use cookie to identify visitor, but I want to personalize content by login user ID(not cookie).

I confirmed that it's possible to create User and Customer Characteristics by Tridion Content Delivery API(Java),PersonalizationDAO interface.

But, when target group is applied to component presentaion,"tridion:TargetGroup" tag is generated automatically,and it uses cookie to identify visitor.

How can I let target group("tridion:TargetGroup" tag) use "login user ID" instead of cookie?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe depends on the environment because in previous versions of Tridion (2011) there were differences in the behaviour of the Profiling between "aspx" and "jsp" pages.

Tridion is going to use cookies always for personalization, but that doesn't means that is not going to use the login id.

When the page is first loaded, it checks for a "request.getRemoteUser()" and if it is there a cookie with the user id of the Tridion Broker Database, then updates the login id in the database.

Try to clean the cookies, and access the page with login, then it creates a cookie with an id, that matches de login id in the user table of the Broker.
If you try to enter with another login, and the cookie is still there, then the database is updated with the new login; but if you clean previously the cookies, then another cookie with another id is created in the database.

Then when all logins have different id's associated in the database, then the cookie get the correct id of their login id.

Comment: I made some try, and it seems that if login ID is added to request attribute named "userId" ,tridion:TargetGroup tag uses the login ID.I'll check out your advdice too.Thanks.